# multisite magento and robots.txt

Tags: magento-1.9, robots.txt, multisite

In robots.txt can be only one directive host.
How right use directive host in robots.txt in magento multisite configuration with many domains?

Answer (score 0):

Create the necessary re-write rule so that any request to the robots.txt file in the domain root is deferred to a custom request handler, for e.g. robots.php in the document root of your Magento installation.

Now, create the request handler robots.php file in the document root of your Magento installation dir:

/home/www-data/public_html/robots.php
Add the following code:

```
<?php


// Parse robots file location using server name
$server_name = 
    isset($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) 
    ? $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] 
    : 'default';
$robots_file = getcwd() .'/robots/'. $server_name .'/robots.txt';

// Check if robot file exists for current domain, else default
$robots_file = 
    file_exists($robots_file) 
    ? $robots_file 
    : getcwd() .'/robots/default/robots.txt';

// Serve robots file
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
header("Content-Length: ". filesize($robots_file));
readfile($robots_file);
exit; ?>
```

Check out this link for more details - [How to serve robots.txt file for multi-store Magento setup](http://www.infinitecodeworks.com/how-to-serve-robots-txt-file-for-multi-store-magento-setup/)

Comment: Its not recommended to only post a link, please write the answer in here